# Running emacs in a docker container

Tags: emacs, docker

I'm using a Mac and want to run emacs in my docker container.  Is there a preferred way to solve this?  In my flow I get stuc because the DISPLAY/TERM aren't set

```
> docker exec -it c6a7a76db84c bash
> sudo apt-get install emacs
...
> oot@c6a7a76db84c:/var/log/apache2# emacs
Please set the environment variable DISPLAY or TERM (see `tset').
> oot@c6a7a76db84c:/var/log/apache2# tset
tset: unknown terminal type unknown
Terminal type?
```

What should I use for tset?  Or is there a preferred way to run emacs in a docker container?

Comment: This isn't really a good idea. Containers work well for services, not interactive applications. All the input and output is being multiplexed over an http channel from the process (emacs) to the Docker CLI via the Docker daemon.

Comment: Are you using Boot2Docker?  What are you trying to achieve by running emacs in this way?

Comment: Thanks @bryan.  I want to edit some of the code that was checked out by the Docker instance to help develop the codebase.

eg the Docker command ran "git clone repo ... "

And I want to edit the files which were cloned.

Comment: I guess the correct thing is to use volumes somehow.  So I end up editing the files locally.

Comment: @Bryan I don't understand why you think Docker doesn't work well with interactive applications. I regularly use it for such!

Comment: I believe I explained that - it involves a lot of extra overhead shipping characters across an http link.

Comment: @Bryan emacs lisp can be used as a scripting language. This is particularly useful for reliably publishing websites written in org-mode to HTML. `emacs --script` is what you want for this, and Docker is the perfect tool to reliably publish from a CI env.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to edit files inside a container, it's generally best to use volumes and the editor on the host, as Bryan suggests. In fact, you should never edit a file that's not in a volume as your changes will be lost when the container is removed.

However, it's quite possible and useful to run editors and even GUI applications inside containers. In order to run the command line version of emacs, all I had to do was:

```
$ docker run -it debian /bin/bash
root@02bd877c1052:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y emacs23-nox
root@02bd877c1052:/# emacs
```

I've tested this with boot2docker and docker running natively on Linux. I think your problem was because emacs was trying to launch the X version of emacs, which won't work by default as there isn't an XServer running.

If you want to run a GUI application inside a container, you have a few choices:

- Use VNC or similar
- Use ssh -x to do X forwarding (requires an XServer such as [xquartz](http://www.xquartz.org/))
- Mount the xsocket inside the container (again requires an XServer and I'm not sure how it will work with xquartz, also there are some security issues with exposing the xsocket)

Please don't believe that containers shouldn't be used for interactive applications. There are many reasons to do so, including security. The [subuser project](http://subuser.org/) uses Docker to run interactive applications and goes into detail about why this can be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks!  In your example is 'debian' the new container name?  Or something special?  Because when I follow what you did, emacs is installed.  But if I attach to an existing container (docker exec -it 0248677d59c2 /bin/bash) it can't find the emacs package to install

Comment: `debian` is the name of the image we are using. You might have been using `ubuntu`. Did you run `apt-get update`?

Comment: I ran apt-get update.  The docker file starts with 'FROM debian:jessie' so I don't think its ubuntu

Comment: I tried emacs24-nox, but it also requires term to be set

Comment: TERM is set to xterm for me. Try just doing `export TERM=xterm` before running emacs. Possibly it's a bug in docker or boot2docker.

Comment: @JohnMontague and in the DockerFile you can use `RUN echo export TERM=xterm >> /etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: `E: Package 'emacs23-nox' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 11):

As Adrian Mouat mentioned [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083182/running-emacs-in-a-docker-container#comment42706218_27091415), just do:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

and you'll be able to run emacs (note, though, that you'll always have to double-enter C-p to move to previous line, because Docker).

Comment: Another thing I'm doing on Docker more and more recently is edit in emacs on my desktop, copy the whole file to clipboard and then inside the container do `cat > file.txt`, paste the clipboard and enter Ctrl+D.

Comment: This is the correct answer. All other answer deserve `/dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Running an editor inside the container isn't really a good idea. Containers work well for services, not interactive applications. If you try it, all the input and output is being multiplexed over an http channel from the process (emacs) to the Docker CLI via the Docker daemon.  Also if the files you are editing are within the container's layered filesystem then that adds extra overhead too.

As [Docker say](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), volumes are a better option:

> you can also mount a directory from your own host into a container.

```
$ sudo docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

> This will mount the local directory, /src/webapp, into the container as the /opt/webapp directory. This is very useful for testing, for example we can mount our source code inside the container and see our application at work as we change the source code.

Note that [as from Docker 1.3](http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/) the `-v` switch will also work from the outer Mac.

Comment: I don't really see the problem with using containers for interactive applications and regularly do so myself.