# emacs when implementing a linux shell

Tags: c, linux, emacs

i'm working on a school project that is a  mini linux shell implementation 
I've finished all the things that they asked me to do
but when i write in my shell the command "emacs"
My shell return a error message "Please set the environment variable TERM; see `tset'."
knowing that vim and all other executables are working.
and all that's all the environment variables in my linux shell :

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Xy6gRH9Mm5/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.w6n2eFUJIt/Render
COLORFGBG=7;0
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PWD=/Users/helmanso/Desktop/w
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SECURITYSESSIONID=186bd
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.2.5
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/munki
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
TERM=xterm
HOME=/Users/helmanso
TMPDIR=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000490000128/T/
USER=helmanso
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
LOGNAME=helmanso
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x448:0:0
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:6CFA1D4A-182E-4981-B8D2-C8AAAD0FBADF
SHLVL=1
OLDPWD=/Users/helmanso/Desktop/w
_=/Users/helmanso/Desktop/w/./a.out
```

Comment: Have you thought to try setting the environment variable TERM?

Comment: yes i did but nothing changed ;(

Comment: try `emacs -nw` to run emacs in your shell?

Comment: $>ファックユーemacs -nw
Please set the environment variable TERM; see `tset'.

Comment: It's probably how your code runs commands that is the problem - see if you can produce a simple [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and that might lead to an answer

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that your shell isn't connected to the X server.  Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083182/running-emacs-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: It says to "see `tset`"; did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue by unsetting `TERM` in my shell, and can confirm that `vim` does indeed run without a `TERM`.

It very much sounds as if you have not *exported* your `TERM` environment variable, such that inferior commands will see it.

e.g. in bash:

```
$ unset TERM
$ emacs -nw
Please set the environment variable TERM; see 'tset'.
$ TERM=xterm
$ emacs -nw
Please set the environment variable TERM; see 'tset'.
$ export TERM
$ emacs -nw
(works)
```

Comment: i didn't creat a export function for my shell

Comment: Well that rather sounds like your issue then.  You could perhaps work around that by running the command `env TERM=xterm emacs -nw`

Comment: or just export the variable in the shell you start your shell from